# ¿De que capacidad debo adquirir hosting para almacenar una pagina web sencilla?

Tags: javascript, php, html5, css3, bootstrap-carousel

La pagina solo permite visualizar contenido y esta hecha con php, css, javascript, html5 y bootstrap, quiero comprarm dominio y alojarla en un hosting pero aun no decido que capacidad de almacenamiento es la mas adecuada para un hosting que albergue este tipo de paginas web. 500mb? 1000mb? 5000mb?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no tiene que ver con la programación. Si sabes ingles puedes mirar en http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ¿Sin base de datos ni nada en especial? Mi recomendación es que busques el hosting con menos capacidad y más barato que encuentres. La página que describes es tan sumamente sencilla que cualquier hosting con PHP (básicamente todos) sería suficiente. Si buscas online vas a encontrar muchos hosting gratuitos con capacidad de 100MB o menos y que, por la descripción que das, deberían valerte a no ser que tengas imágenes y ficheros grandes.

Comment: Fuera del tema, por que tiene un positivo esta pregunta? no va con la sección ni tampoco llega a tener sentido alguno de utilidad.